# Iterate over ExecutionResult returning Relationships

Tags: java, neo4j

```
String query1 =  "START
  a=node:node_auto_index(name=\"A\"),
  m=node:node_auto_index(name=\"M\"),
  b=node:node_auto_index(name=\"G\")
  MATCH  p=a-[*]-b-[*]-m " + 
  WHERE ALL(r in RELS(p) WHERE r.value >= 200) " 
  +   "WITH a, m, MIN(LENGTH(p)) AS l
  MATCH p=a-[*]-b-[*]-m WHERE ALL(r 
   in RELS(p) WHERE r.value >= 200)" +
  " AND LENGTH(p)=l RETURN p order by length(p) desc "; //limit 2
ExecutionResult eResult = exEngine.execute(query1);
```

I am using above query to  get all paths between two nodes. how can I iterate over returning RelationShips.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using following approach, the link posted above helped.

`final Iterator rels = eResult.columnAs("p");`

```
        while (rels.hasNext()){
            Path path = rels.next();

            Iterable<Relationship>  relationships = path.relationships();
            java.util.Iterator<Relationship> relIterator = relationships.iterator();
            while (relIterator.hasNext()){
                Relationship rel = relIterator.next();
                String aNode = (String) rel.getStartNode().getProperty("name");
                String zNode = (String) rel.getEndNode().getProperty("name");
                Long value = (Long) rel.getProperty("value");
                System.out.println(aNode +" is connected to "+zNode + " with value "+value);


            }

        }
    </code>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just `return rels(p) as rels` to just return the relationships. Or `nodes(p)` ftm.

If you are just interested in the names of the nodes of the path use extract.

```
return extract(n in nodes(p) : n.name) as names
```